# Regarding Deployment of Rails application using nginx+passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, passenger, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy my rails application. After I performed `cap deploy production` everything worked perfectly. Then I restarted nginx server, it showed OK status.

I opened the address in Browser and I get 500 error, We're sorry but some thing went wrong!

I opened the log using `less log/production.log` , it is showing me all the migrations and seed running perfectly. But there is no sign of pages getting loaded.

I can't see any sign of GET requests going on! Can anyone tell me a way to get over this!

Thank you!

Comment: And what did the nginx log say?

Comment: How do we check nginx log ? Is it error.log , can you tell me how to view it ?

Comment: The best way to know which file it is would be to look at your nginx config for the server log definition. If there isn't one then yes, I'd say error.log is your best bet (access.log will be it's partner) -- you can view it will less, or cat or tail to watch it in real time

Comment: Thank you ! I will check it out and get back !

Comment: Hai I tried to look into error.log and production.log, they are not getting updated !

Comment: It is looking for public/index.html in the beginning, so I added index.html to my app in public and done the process again. Now when I open my server in browser it is correctly showing that content. But I want index.html.erb to show up! I tried rendering in home controller but its not working

Comment: @trh can you help me with the problem?

Comment: please post your config/routes.rb file

Comment: In my routes.rb, I have root "public#index" and other get routes

Comment: Can you paste the file in your question?

Comment: Hai @trh please check this out ! I mentioned everything here now!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482125/deployment-of-rails-app-using-nginx-passenger-and-capistrano

Sorry ! I gave wrong link before!