# Deployment of Rails app using nginx, passenger and capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, passenger, digital-ocean

I am deploying my first rails application. I have some trouble doing that. I will describe what I did till now.

1) I configured everything correctly by going through gorails.com

2) I am trying to deploy it on Digital Ocean

3) I performed `cap deploy production` and the end result was successful with some failures in middle.

4) I started nginx server

5) In my browser it gave me 500 error.

6) I checked my `production.log` and it showed all the migrations and seeds that it ran. It created tables perfectly (As I checked in my db too).

7) I checked nginx `error.log` and it showed that index.html is missing.

8) So in order to check, I added index.html file in public directory and browser displayed the content correctly.

9) But my landing page is index.html.erb in home controller, so in routes file I have done some modifications but no change in the output in browser.

10) And I have noticed that error.log and production.log are not updating instantly. I dont know why.

11) I need help in making nginx display my index.html.erb file and connecting it with rails app. Database is configured correctly.

12) My nginx config file is :

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name digital_ocean_ip;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /home/myapp/myapp/current/public;
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

Here my user name and my application names are same so (/myapp/myapp)

13) My routes.rb file is :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  root "public#index"
  get 'access/logout'
  get '/signup' => "users#signup"
  get '/register' => "users#signup"
  get '/login' => "access#login"
  get '/' => "home#index"

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :confirm_email
    end
    collection do
      post :search
    end
  end

  resources :books do
    collection do
      get :recent
      get :academic
      get :novels
      get :preparation
    end
  end
  resources :password_resets

  match '/users/show' => 'users#books', :via=> :get
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get,:post]

  get '*path' => redirect('404')
end
```

14) My deploy.rb file is:

```
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'myapp'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:user_name/myapp.git'


set :deploy_to, '/home/myapp/myapp'

role :app, %w{Digitalocean_ip}
role :web, %w{Digitalocean_ip}
role :db,  %w{Digitalocean_ip}
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs) + %w{public/uploads}
set :assets_dependencies, %w(app/assets lib/assets vendor/assets Gemfile config/routes.rb)

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  desc 'Runs rake db:seed'
  task :seed => [:set_rails_env] do
  on primary fetch(:migration_role) do
    within release_path do
      with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
        execute :rake, "db:seed"
      end
    end
  end
end

  after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'

end
```

15) My production.rb file is:

```
set :stage, :production

server 'Digitalocean_ip', user: 'myapp', roles: %w{web app db}
```

16) These are all my config files. Please tell me where its going wrong

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set your root path to home#index, instead of public#index

Comment: Should I render public/index.html.erb from home controller??

Comment: Or can I directly render home index view?

Comment: the controller will automatically render the index view on the index action.  That's part of rails magic.  (unless you manually change the render) - so you don't have to put anything in the controller action to render.

Comment: Should I keep index.html.erb view of home controller in public directory?

Comment: no - your index.html.erb should be in app/views/home/index.html.erb

Comment: Ok ! I will try these changes and deploy again and restart the server!

Comment: It it showing 500 error again ! My index action is as follows:

`class HomeController < ApplicationController`

  `layout 'application'`

  `def index`

    `if session[:user_id]`

      `redirect_to(:controller=>'users', :action=>'index')`
    else
     
    end
  end

end

Comment: I am sorry, cant send code perfectly here! `code`

Comment: It it showing 500 error again ! My index action is as follows:

`class HomeController < ApplicationController`

  `layout 'application'`

  `def index`

    `if session[:user_id]`

      `redirect_to(:controller=>'users', :action=>'index')`

    `else`
     
    `end`

  `end`

`end`

Comment: @trh can you please tell me where its going wrong! Been working on it from few days!

Comment: And my log is not updating ! I am checking `current/log/produciton.log` and `var/log/nginx/error.log` . I cant find a way to look for the problem.

Comment: Does this application work in development?

Comment: Yeah ! It works perfectly !

Comment: Here I cant even see the index page !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108551/discussion-between-trh-and-saiteja-reddy).